# Как реализовать автоматическую загрузку картинки?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Есть код , который позволяет загрузить изображение, после того как скопирован url в инпут. Попытался вставить url после загрузки страницы в инпут. Но , что-то не полчается... Подскажите как правильно сделать ?

Html :

```
 <input placeholder="Введите урл картинки" autofocus type="text" id="myinput"/>
```

Js.

```
 window.onload = function () {

    document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {

        var link = document.createElement('a');

        link.href = this.value;

        link.download = 'yandex.png';

        link.click();

    }, false);
    var str = $("#myinput").val()
        var leed = "http://media.kg-portal.ru/images/shrek3/shrek3_46.jpg"
        $("#myinput").val(leed)

 };
```

Вот весь код на фидле : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/126/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему ты хочешь сделать автоматическую загрузку фото. Например в Яндексе и Гугле, чтобы загрузить фото из интернета, нужно нажать кнопку. Вот пример, как это можно сделать на `php`:

```
<form method="get">
  Введите URL:<br><input type="text" name="url"/>
   <input type="submit" value=" загрузить "/>
</form>
```

Php:

```
if (!empty($_GET['url']))
 {
 $file = basename($_GET['url']);
 if (file_get_contents($_GET['url']))
  {
  $content = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
  $f = fopen( "$file", "w" );
  if (fwrite( $f, $content ) === FALSE)
   {
   echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл.";
   exit;
   }else echo "Ура! Файл <font color='red'>" .$file ."</font> записан.";
  fclose( $f );
  }else echo "Не могу считать файл.";
 }
```